# How do I proceed further when my reports of a improper functioning of a gnome component has not met with answers on the respective mailing list

Tags: networking, gnome, networkmanager

I am unable to connect to internet using my modem. I followed instructions to seek help at http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging and posted on http://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-October/msg00194.html.

There was an initial response from the mailing list, but now its silent. What should I do in this situation? Do I go ahead and just file a bug at bugzilla.gnome.org?

Though I am competent enough to help somebody fixing bugs by providing required more information, I am not competent enough to try and help fixing the bug myself.

Comment: Just a note; as of March 2014; the https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging returns "This page does not exist yet. You can create a new empty page, or use one of the page templates."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it *worked* with the last release and doesn't with the latest, I'd say it's a bug. You could file one [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) and if they consider it an upstream issue at GNOME's bug tracker.

Beside filing a bug report, you could

- try dropping by [the #gnome IRC channel](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeIrcChannels), maybe prepared with your logs [pasted somewhere](http://pastie.org/).
- look for [a little more Ubuntu-specific help](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mobile+broadband)

Comment: Also since it works with wvdial, it's probably not an issue with the kernel driver.